# TOP 2 faster than TOP 1 in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, full-text-search

we have a table with +- 500k rows in Sql Server 2005 database and one of its columns has a full-text index.

We were doing some tests and found that SELECT TOP 1 ... WHERE CONTAINS(fullTextColumn, 'anyValue') was taking more than two minutes to return. However the same select, but with TOP 2 instead of 1 return in a few seconds.

Any idea on why this happens?

Thanks!

**Edit: Some more information about the problem. On TOP 1 query plan Sql use a Remote Scan while in TOP 2 it uses Index Seek. Very odd.**

**Edit 2: These are both Execution Plans from Sql:**

TOP 1

```
StmtText
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |--Top(TOP EXPRESSION:((1)))
       |--Nested Loops(Left Semi Join, WHERE:([ECRReload].[dbo].[TECR_PRODUTO_COMPLETO_VENDAVEIS].[idProduto] = [Full-text Search Engine].[KEY]))
            |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([ECRReload].[dbo].[TECR_PRODUTO_COMPLETO_VENDAVEIS].[ix_tecr_produto_completo_vendaveis01]))
            |--Remote Scan(OBJECT:(CONTAINS))
```

TOP 2

```
StmtText
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |--Top(TOP EXPRESSION:((2)))
       |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Full-text Search Engine].[KEY]))
            |--Remote Scan(OBJECT:(CONTAINS))
            |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([ECRReload].[dbo].[TECR_PRODUTO_COMPLETO_VENDAVEIS].[ix_tecr_produto_completo_vendaveis01]), SEEK:([ECRReload].[dbo].[TECR_PRODUTO_COMPLETO_VENDAVEIS].[idProduto]=[Full-text Search Engine].[KEY]) ORDERED FORWARD)
```

Comment: Did you run the tests more than once? Otherwise the result is simply cached from the first query.

Comment: SQL Servers cache the results and that way a following query is usually a lot faster which would explain for your results.

Comment: Actually no. We ran it for 5 minutes and stopped.

Comment: Use (if it's not production database) 
`DBCC freeproccache
GO
DBCC dropcleanbuffers
GO`
to clear stats before each query call and repeat your tests.

Comment: It´s prod. I will show this command to the DBA to see what he thinks. We are researching this like crazy here! ehehe

Comment: Could you please both execution plans as they are? Run `SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON \n GO \n SELECT …`

Comment: `Remote scan` means it is scanning rows in a table stored in a database or file other than the current database server. If there are two separate database servers involved, there are twice as many variables affecting run time. Have you repeated with consistent results?

Comment: @OrbMan: a `FULLTEXT` catalog is considered a remote source as well, and a `Remote Scan` is what is normally used to retrieve the list of `KEY INDEX` values from the catalog to join with the actual table. I wonder what is the `Index Seek` the @op mentioned.

Comment: @Quassnoi: interesting, thanks for clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´m not 100% sure if I can say that this is fixed, but it seems to be. Last night our DBA rebuilt the FullText catalog and reorganized and it started to work. Both queries now run with less than a second.

I can´t explain why, but it is working.